# Bad performance on rotation when using UIView mask

Tags: ios, ipad, core-animation, calayer, masking

I have a couple of UITableViews which should fade out at the top. They are placed next to each other in a single UIView. Since all the table views are supposed to fade at the same place, I figured that I should set an alpha mask on the container UIView. This works fine, the scrolling is smooth in all table views and the fade looks nice.

The problem is when the interface orientation changes. It's REALLY choppy. And only when the mask is applied. If I remove the fade, everything is smooth.

This is the code for applying said mask:

```
// If you want the Table Views to "fade out" at the top, use this function to set the height!
- (void) setFadeHeight:(CGFloat)fadeHeight
{
    if (fadeHeight == 0.0) {
        self.layer.mask = nil;
        return;
    }

    // Create a gradient layer to use as mask
    CAGradientLayer *l = [self createGradientLayerWithHeight:fadeHeight];
    l.shouldRasterize = NO;
    [self.layer setMask:l];
}

// Creates a transparency gradient. Helper function for the above function
- (CAGradientLayer *) createGradientLayerWithHeight:(CGFloat)gradientHeight
{
    CAGradientLayer *mask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    mask.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                      nil];

    mask.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (__bridge id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor,
                   (__bridge id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                   nil];

    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);

    // vertical direction
    mask.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0); 
    mask.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, gradientHeight / self.bounds.size.height);
    return mask;
}
```

The issue might be related to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520941/core-animation-calayer-mask-animation-performance), but since I have smooth scrolling in my tables I'm not so sure. I've also tried setting shouldRasterize to NO according to the answers in that question.

Comment: What happens if you remove the mask in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and add it back in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`? How does that look? Does it look strange that the mask would not be applied during the rotation?

Comment: Yeah, it looks okay. But it's disturbing when you know it's there. It'll have to do if no one comes up with a better solution. Thanks.